# tesseract return reversed words with arabic

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, arabic, python-tesseract

***hello everyone I'm trying to extract a license number plate from    Tunisian cars  so i decided to use tesseract to extract the numbers    and word 'تونس' so before that i installed tesseract-OCR v5.0.0 for    windows 10 and i wanted to try on an image with Arabic words but i    got this result words are reversed i didn't know how to fix this***

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdxQE.png)

this is the code I've been used

> 

```
import pytesseract
import cv2

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

text1= cv2.imread ('text.jpg')

text=pytesseract.image_to_string(text1 , lang='ara')
print(text)
cv2.imshow("img",text1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: You've probably already tested this, but it might be an issue with VS Code rather than tesseract - does other arabic text (say, a string literal) get printed the right way around?

Comment: it's the same probleme